# Confused by the capitalisation of titles when they are plural

Tags: english, grammar

Worked on a project with General Managers be capitalised. If I had written Chief Executive Officer, then I'd say yes as it's clearly referring to a person. However, in this case I'm referring to multiple managers so am not sure whether to capitalise or not.

Comment: Personally I would not "uncapitalize" something just because I'm switching from singular to plural, or vice versa.  See also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/407537/not-duplicate-president-vs-president-has-there-been-a-change-in-what-is-g

Comment: Hi and welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. This is a site for questions about methods and hard-to-find resources for learning or teaching languages. Questions asking to explain aspects of a specific language's spelling or grammar are off topic here.